# Which toolbox do I use to create GUI softwares

Tags: user-interface

Good night, I'm new here nad I want your help

I want to learn how to create GUI softwares with code::blocks and have seen a topic talking about GTK+ and wxWidget

I want to know which of them is better and easier to use

thanks

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Or are you hoping for a cross-platform GUI? Also, I'm guessing based on your post that your language of choice is C/C++? I should also note that code::blocks is not a GUI framework, it is simply an IDE.

Comment: Yes, my language is C/C++. What IDE do you suggest? visual studio? And my target is the windows.

Comment: Fair warning: This question will be flagged and removed  because it is primarily opinion based. That being said, my opinion is that wxWidgets is a good way to go. It is easy to use and has a robust set of features. As I said, this entirely opinion based. Whichever you choose, I'm sure it will do the job you are attempting to do. Qt is also widely used (my favorite), and is very good to know. The only drawback is that if you deploy it in software for sale, then you have to pay a license fee.